# RabbitMQ no config file

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq

I installed RabbitMQ directly on my PC but there is no config file. I need it to enable TLS. Any idea where it could be or how I could create it? I looked into the standart %APPDATA%/Roaming/RabbitMQ/ but there was only a enable_plugins file.

Any idea where the config file is or how I can create it?

Answer (score 0):

You must create the file yourself with a text editor.